# Firefox is loading css but not applying. I tried other browsers and all of them working well

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox

http://rioblanco.hlsecuador.com

I am developing this site. If you browse using firefox then style.css file is not working. Firebug does not show the rules of the style.css file. But If you viewsource then it shows the whole file.

THe stylesheet url is: http://rioblanco.hlsecuador.com/wp-content/themes/hacendario/style.css

Please help me out... It is pulling my hair off

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this problem too with my css...

If you check http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator you can validate your css. If you have Parse error in your code, firefox simply stops reading next lines. And obviously you have parse error :)

```
30   #bookpage   Parse Error ('mages/backgroundgrey.jpg)repeat; }
```

(You are missing ' behind `.jpg` - `background-image: url ('mages/backgroundgrey.jpg') repeat;` would be correct)

**EDIT:**
It looks like you have the image in `images` folder, so change the path to `images/backgroundgrey.jpg` to load the image

**EDIT2:**
valid code will look like:

```
#bookpage{
  background: url('images/backgroundgrey.jpg') repeat;
}
```